GMap.NET - Session based authentication
I am maintaining an older code (.NET Framework 4.6) that uses GMap.NET library to create maps of our customer. However one of the servers, that is giving us the maps now requires username and password and for further communication to include session cookie. Is there a way to ensure this behavior in GMap.NET? (Here follows information from customer:
"Session-based authentication:
Login with /auth/login by entering username and password. The
role can be omitted for a user who only has one role,
can be dispensed with. The creation of a special user with only one role
is recommended.
A session cookie is returned that the calling http client
must send with every request. This happens, for example, when using the
Apache HttpClient object.
Error messages
Errors are transmitted via a status not equal to 200 and a plain text error message
in the body, e.g.
Login failed
Example:
http://<server>>:8080/swebserver/auth/login/?username=wms&password=secret
There is also a token-based authentication, this can be found in the appendix"
I tried to look through the functionality of this library, but I must admit I am quite lost.
